# How to upload json file to Azure?

Tags: http, delphi, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to [PUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) a Json file to the Azure cloud.
No matter what I do, I get a 201 (ok) response from the server, but the file is NOT uploaded.
I can read the list of files on the server but that's it. I don't have access to the Log to see the actual error.

```
function ReadBytesAsStream(const AFileName: string): TStream;
begin
  Result := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
end;


function SendFileToCloud(AFilename: String; ShowErrors: Boolean): Boolean;
CONST
   Container= 'MyContainer/';
   BaseURL  = 'https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/'+ Container;
   JWT      = 'sp=rcwl&st=2022-10-04T00:00:26Z&'
             +'se=2025-12-31T21:00:26Z&spr=https&'
             +'sv=2021-06-08&'                                                    // SAS authorization token:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json
             +'sr=c&sig=blablabla';
VAR
  FinalURL: String;
  FileName: String;
  FileContent: TStream;
  RESTClient: TRESTClient;
  RESTRequest: TRESTRequest;
  RESTResponse: TRESTResponse;
begin
  Result:= TRUE;
  RESTClient:= NIL;
  RESTRequest:= NIL;
  RESTResponse:= NIL;

  // Create URL.
  FileName := ExtractFileName(aFilename);       
  FinalURL := BaseURL + FileName + '?' + JWT;

  VAR sText:= ReadTextFromFile(AFileName); // Try to send as text

  TRY
    // create REST objects
    RESTClient   := TRESTClient.Create(FinalURL);
    RESTRequest  := TRESTRequest.Create(RESTClient);
    RESTResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(RESTClient);

      RESTRequest.Client    := RESTClient;
      RESTRequest.Response  := RESTResponse;
      RESTRequest.Method  := TRestRequestMethod.rmPUT;

      // HEADER
      RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
      RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('x-ms-version', '2021-06-08',  TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
      RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('x-ms-date', '2023-02-28',     TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);

      // FILE BODY
      RESTRequest.AddBody(AnsiString(sText), ctAPPLICATION_JSON);  

      RESTRequest.Execute;

  FINALLY
    RESTResponse.Free;
    RESTRequest.Free;
    RESTClient.Free;
  END;
end;
```

PS: I cut down the try/except and other irrelevant parts of the code to make the code more readable.

Comment: 201 is not an error. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201

Comment: Hi Mjn. I never said that 201 is an error :) 
I get a 201 response from the server but the file is not uploaded.

Comment: 201 means the resource was successfully created. Important details are missing: what does "I can read the list of files on the server but that's it. " actually mean - is the new file in this list? And how do you read the list of files, using some web interface or by (Delphi) code?

Comment: Both. I can see the listing directly in Azure, but I also made a utility program to list the files in the cloud. But I don't have access to the log.

Comment: Do the opposite: `GET https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/MyContainer/file.ext` and see what happens then.

Comment: And, is the file in the listing?

Comment: Give me until tomorrow. The code might be ok. There are some clues that the problem is on the server. God knowd what they are doing there. I promise I will let you know tomorrow